# Use one environment to run examples using roxygen2

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2, package-development

I am writing a package in R that essentially carries out a pipeline. This pipeline has several stages that the user can adapt depending on what they would like to achieve.

One of the earliest stages requires running a function that is time consuming.

I would like to create an environment, or have some kind of work around, in which this stage is run once and I can simply refer back to this processed environment when I am using `@examples` to create a runnable example using `roxygen2`.

I do not want to use `\dontrun{}` as I would like to publish the package and I am required to have runnable examples.

Thank you and apologies if my problem is not clear.

Comment: ...assign it as a variable?

Comment: but how can re use this variable across different examples?

Comment: I guess you could group the documentation of multiple functions into one with `@rdname`, though that may not be a good idea. Or you could just add the completed object to the package as data.

Comment: This could work but I was hoping for a slightly less cumbersome solution where there is no need to store an extra data object that would be directly accessible to the user

Comment: You're asking to have your cake and eat it too. Examples are intended to be run by the user, so they must be independently complete. If you want data to be reused, it has to come from somewhere, and if it's in multiple documentation pages, it either needs to be reproduced in each or stored. Or group the pages into one. Or chuck the whole example in a vignette.